# Get facet results only in Solr

Tags: solr, facet

I am trying to make search on my database using Solr, and i need to build a facet for the date of the articles(2011-6-12,2011-7-1 ..etc) and another facet for category(sport, news..etc) i built my php code using apache_solr_service and every thing is fine till now, i can do search for my data in the database, but i want to use facet to filter the articles that are created in specific date or to get the articles that belong to a specific category,

i used:

**http://localhost:8888/solr/collection1/select?facet=true&facet.query=datecreated:2011-6-21&facet.mincount=1&wt=json&json.nl=map&q=ruba&start=0&rows=10**

its returned all the articles that have 'ruba' word and give me the count of articles that have been created in 2011-6-21.

what i need is to get only the articles that have ruba word **AND** are created on 2011-6-21, i want only **facet results** to be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using filter query, fq=datecreated:2011-6-21 instead of facet

Comment: what if I want to get results in the faceted form for example: 

Gender:M : {All results with Gender = M}
Gender:F : {All results with Gender = F}